# Will time-consuming RPC block the heartbeat and so cause timeout in JGroups?

Tags: java, block, rpc, jgroups

I'm using TCP protocol in my jgroups program and set FD_ALL.timeout to 12000ms FD_ALL.interval=4000ms. 
sending code like

```
MessageDispatcher.sendMessage(message, new RequestOptions(ResponseMode.GET_ALL, 4000))
```

RequestHandler code like this:

```
public Object handle(Message message) {
     //time consuming code
    }
```

sometimes it cost more then 12000ms to handle the message.
my question is when that happend will it block the heartbeat packet until timeout? and so cause a viewAccepted event indicate the left of that peer?

Answer (score 1):

If your expected service time is *N* your timeout should be *2N,* as a rule of thumb.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will only block the sending thread and the next sending thread(if exists a netxt send)